# Real analysis question - inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g, h: [−2,1] → [3,5]$ and define $f: [−2,1] → \mathbb R$ by $f(x)= \dfrac{ g(x)}{ h(x)(x^3 - 2x - 15)}$.  Which of the following inequalities must hold for all $x$ in the interval $[−2, 1]$?

(a) $|f(x)| ≤ \dfrac 59$

(b) $|f(x)| ≤ \dfrac{ g(1)}{19h(-2)}$

(c) $|f(x)| ≤ \dfrac{g(-2)}{16h(1)}$

(d) $|f(x)| ≤  \dfrac{|g(-2)|}{19|h(-2)|}$

(e) $|f(x)| ≤ \dfrac{g(1)}{16h(1)}$

How would you solve this kind of problem? This was on my midterm and I got it wrong, and I can't figure out how to do it. The correct answer is (a) $|f(x)| ≤ \dfrac 59$, so could someone please explain how to get to that answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$3 \le g(x) \le 5$ and $h(x) \ge 3$ for all $x \in [-2,1]$ so that $\dfrac{|g(x)|}{|h(x)|} \le \dfrac 53$. Now use some calculus to determine the maximum value of $\dfrac 1{|x^3 - 2x -15|}$ in that interval.

Comment: I don't understand why 3 ≤ g(x) ≤ 5 and h(x) ≥ 3.  Why wouldn't it be 3 ≤ g,h ≤ 5?